# Should I compute or store these cumulative sums in a table?

Tags: database-design

I need to be able to access data in such format from a SQL Server and a Sybase databases (`date, product` is the key).

```
date, product, dailyProfit, monthlyCumulativeprofit, yearlyCumulativeProfit
```

At the moment, a project I am taking over has such table in which `dailyProfits` get updated, added, removed... As a result, it seems like the existing code damaged the Monthly Cumulative Profits, as well as the Yearly Cumulative Profits.

To overcome the problem and not have to dig in the code + recover the integrity of the table, could I have a table such as :

```
date, product, dailyProfit
```

which would receive INSERTs, UPDATEs, DELETEs, and use some mechanism (triggers? or is that risky given the fact that this smaller table contains in average **3 million rows**?) that would give me a synchronized view containing cumulative sums, in a more automated and trusted way...

What is your opinion on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever practical, avoid storing redundant data. If you store both the individual values and the total, then you create the possibility that the total may not really match the sum of the individual values. This can lead to mysterious bugs, where a function that reads the individual values gives different results than a function that uses the stored total. If you're lucky, someone notices that the value on screen A is different from the value on screen B and you can investigate and fix it. But if things are more complex, like you use one set of values for selection criteria and another for display, it may be that no one will ever notice.

Keeping the values in sync can be a major programming headache, depending on just what the relationship is. If you're lucky, you may be able to set up some triggers that automatically update the total every time an individual value is added, changed, or deleted, so at least this is only done in one place.

But the key phrase here is "whenever practical". To take a simple example: Every time a user accesses his bank account, he probably wants to see the balance. If to display that we have to add up every transaction since he opened the account, possibly many years ago, that could be a performance killer.

So store redundant totals when you have to, but only when you have to. If you must store redundant totals, keep as few levels as possible. I wouldn't store daily totals, weekly totals, monthly totals, and annual totals. I'd try to pick one level for totals and keep it to that. Like you can probably recalculate daily and weekly totals on the fly. Maybe keep monthly, then you can calculate annual by adding up 12 months. Or maybe just keep annual for long-term calculation, and everything less calculate on the fly. It all depends on how many records you have and what outputs you need. But every extra total is one more thing to keep in sync, and thus one more potential problem.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what database you're using and data usage information.  Having pre-aggregated data can lead to outdated information so some caution is advised.  Whenever possible, "on-the-fly" calculation should be preferred (especially if performance was not an issue).

Here are a few more options to explore. Indexed/Materialized view ([link](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/indexed-views-in-sql-server-2000)) or using M-Olap cubes to pre-aggregate information.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you often request cumulative sums then it would be a good idea to store them, because computing them with every request will use a lot of resources.

You can set up triggers so you increase cumulative values on add and decrease on remove. On update you update adequately.

For the same reason internet forums usually have post count per user, despite the fact that posts could be of course counted with every request (which would have a huge performance impact). The trigger just increases the counter when the new post is added and decreases when the post is removed.